# Why can't I update ad hoc iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, installation, adhoc

I have a script working well for creating ad hoc iPhone builds.  I can drop the app and mobileprovision file on iTunes (Mac version), and it installs to the device without a problem.  But if I generate a new build and drop the files on iTunes a second time, I always get the dreaded "could not be verified" error on sync.

The only thing that fixes the problem is to delete the app and profile from the desktop and device, sync, and then drop the new copy and sync again.  I've tried every variation of deleting the profile or app on only the device or desktop, and nothing other than cleaning out both will fix it.

Does anyone know if this a bug in the installation process for ad hoc apps, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you changing your version for each build?

I don't remember getting an error message, but I found that if I did not change the version information each time, I could not drag and drop to install the new version. I would need to delete the app first.

Not sure if this will help, but it is the only thing I can think of so far.

Comment: yes. In your info.plist file there's a version number entry. If you leave the version number the same, it just thinks the new copy is identical to the old copy I think...